# How to Get Joined Table Data Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a two models which are

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string PostImage { get; set; }
    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PublishedDate { get; set; }
    public string  CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

And that generates the `CategoryPosts` table.

Here is my question: I want to get data from the `CategoryPosts` table to calculate popular categories. How can I reach that data?  And what is the best way to do that?

Comment: If you need that as a business entity, define it as a business entity (define the class)

Comment: Is there anyway solve that problem with LinQ ? Why should i define another class?

Comment: A. Why not? B. Because if you want to use the fictionally of such an entity, define it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the popular categories you don't need to map the juction table, you can order the `Categories` by the count of post:

```
var query=yourContext.Categories.OrderBy(c=>c.Posts.Count);
```

If you have disabled lazy loading then you should call the Include method before:

```
var query=yourContext.Categories.Include(c=>c.Posts).OrderBy(c=>c.Posts.Count);
```

As you can see below, the SQL code generated is using the junction table to check the count of `Post` that have each `Category` and order by that criteria:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[PostCategories] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Category_Id]) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

The junction table generally is mapped when you need to add an additional column (that excludes both keys of the tables you are joining). In that case you need to create two one-to-many relationships between the juction table and `Post` and `Caterogy` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks octavio ,

I got the idea right now i can easily get like that.

```
   public List<Category> GetPopularCategories()
    {
     return _categoryRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(c => c.Posts.Count).ToList();
    }
```